# Method called while device orientation changed

Tags: ios

If the orientation changed of iPhone which method is called first?

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

If i am coming back to the previous view controller through navigation controller's Back button are these methods called?if called in which sequence?

Comment: So what event is happening; orientation change or back button press?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is only called once. `viewWillAppear` is only called when the view appears. So neither has anything to do with orientation changes. You should read the "View Controller Programming Guide" to learn all about this stuff.

Comment: what about add a breakpoint and try by your self?

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad` is called whenever the view did load. Typically, that will happen if you access the controller's view or it is put on screen.

When it will appear (i.e. is pushed on a `UINavigationController`), the `viewWillAppear:` method gets called (and viewDidAppear: afterwards).

It may happen that a view is loaded multiple times (for example in low memory conditions or if the view gets disposed otherwise). It can happen, but it doesn't have to. `viewWillAppear:` will get called again anyhow (if applicable, it's called after `viewDidLoad`).

It wouldn't make much sense the other way around - there's nothing to configure or to let appear, if the view didn't load yet.

Answer (score 0):

If your class is a UIViewController you can use this method:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

Outside UIViewController you can addListener for rotation notifications.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self     selector:@selector(orientationdidChange:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```